# JDK9 randomization on immutable sets and maps

Tags: java, random, collections, maps, java-9

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45216891/1876620) and [the answer given by Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45217298/1876620), I found that JDK9 immutable sets and maps will introduce a source of randomness that will affect their traversal. This means that *iteration order* will indeed be random, at least among different runs of the JVM.

As the spec doesn't guarantee any traversal/iteration order for sets and maps, this is absolutely fine. In fact, code must never rely on implementation-specific details, but on the spec instead.

I know that today, with JDK 8, if I have i.e. a `HashSet` and do this (taken from the linked answer):

```
Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("just", "a", "test"));

System.out.println(wordSet);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    wordSet.add("" + i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    wordSet.remove("" + i);
}

System.out.println(wordSet);
```

Then the *iteration order* of the elements will change and the two outputs will differ. This is because adding and removing 100 elements to the set changes the internal capacity of the `HashSet` and rehashes elements. And this is perfectly valid behavior. I'm not asking about this here.

However, with JDK9, if I do this:

```
Set<String> set = Set.of("just", "a", "test");
System.out.println(set);
```

And then, in another instance of the JVM, I run the same code, the outputs can be different, because randomization has been introduced.

So far, I've found this excellent [video in youtube (minute 44:55)](https://youtu.be/LgR9ByD1dEw?t=2696), in which Stuart Marks says that one motivation for this randomization is:

> *(...) that people write applications that have inadvertent dependencies on iteration order. (...) So, anyway, iteration order is a big deal and I think there's a lot of code out there that has latent dependencies on iteration order that has not been discovered yet. (...) So, our response to this is to deliberately randomize the iteration order in `Set` and `Map` in the new collections. So whereas before the iteration order of collections was unpredictable but stable, these are predictably unpredictable. So every time the JVM starts up, we get a random number and we use that at as a seed value that gets mixed in with the hash values. So, if you run a program that initializes a set and then prints out the elements in any order, you get an answer, and then, if you invoke the JVM again and run that same program, the set of elements usually would come out in a different order. So, the idea here is that (...) if there are iteration order dependencies in your code, what used to happen in the past, is a new JDK release came out and you test your code and (...) it'd take hours of debugging to trace it down to some kind of change in iteration order. What that meant was there was a bug in that code that depended on the iteration order. Now, if you vary the iteration order more often, like every JVM invocation, then (we hope) that weird behavior will manifest itself more frequently, and in fact we hope while you're doing testing...*

So, the motivation is clear, and it's also clear that this randomization will only affect the new immutable sets and maps.

My question is: **Are there any other motivations for this randomization and what advantages does it have?**

Comment: I welcome this.  I have personally fixed two bugs caused by relying on iteration order of HashSets and HashMaps, in 2017 alone.

Comment: @VGR I also welcome it. I think it's going to be of great help.

Comment: @VGR we had to re-write on average 7% of already existing code when we moved to java8 from 7, because some pieces of code where relying on order of `HashMap`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well it turns out there is another reason for the randomized iteration order. It's not a big secret or anything. I thought I had explained it in that talk, but maybe not. I probably mentioned it on the OpenJDK mailing lists or perhaps in internal discussions.

In any case, another reason for randomized iteration order is to **preserve flexibility for future implementation changes.**

This turns out to be a bigger deal than most people think. Historically, `HashSet` and `HashMap` have never specified a particular iteration order. From time to time, however, the implementation needed to change, to improve performance or to fix bugs. Any change to iteration order generated a lot of flak from users. Over the years, a lot of resistance built up to changing iteration order, and this made maintenance of `HashMap` more difficult.

To see why this is a problem, consider a spectrum of different policies for managing the stability of iteration order:

1. Specify the iteration order, and stick to it.
2. Leave iteration order unspecified, but implicitly keep iteration order stable.
3. Leave iteration order unspecified, but change the iteration order as little as possible.
4. Change the iteration order frequently, e.g., in update releases.
5. Change the iteration order more frequently, e.g., from one run of the JVM to the next.
6. Change the iteration order **even more** frequently, e.g., from one iteration to the next.

When collections were introduced in JDK 1.2, `HashMap` iteration order was unspecified. Stable iteration order was provided by `LinkedHashMap` at a somewhat higher cost. If you didn't need a stable iteration order, you shouldn't have to pay for it. This ruled out #1 and #2.

For the next several releases, we tried to keep iteration order stable, even though the specification allowed it to change. Nobody likes it when code breaks, and it's pretty unpleasant to have to tell a customer that his code is broken because it depends on iteration order.

So we ended up with policy #3, keeping iteration order as stable as possible, although it did change from time to time. For example, we introduced alternative hashing in JDK 7u6 ([code review](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010238.html) for JDK-7118743) and tree bins in JDK 8 ([JEP 180](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180)), and both changed `HashMap` iteration order in some circumstances. Ordering also changed a couple times in earlier releases. Somebody did some archaeology and found that iteration order changed an average of once per major JDK release.

This was the worst of all possible worlds. Major releases only occurred once every couple years. When one came out, everybody's code would break. There would be much wailing and gnashing of teeth, people would fix their code, and we'd promise to never, ever change iteration order again. A couple years would go by and new code would be written that inadvertently depended on iteration order. Then we'd come out with another major release that changed the iteration order, and this would break everybody's code again. And the cycle would begin anew.

I wanted to avoid repeating this cycle for the new collections. Instead of keeping iteration order as stable as possible, I pursued a policy of changing it as frequently as possible. Initially the order changed on *every* iteration, but this imposed some overhead. Eventually we settled on once per JVM invocation. The cost is a 32-bit XOR operation per table probe, which I think is pretty cheap.

To a certain extent this is about "toughening up" application code. If changing iteration order breaks code, then breaking that code more frequently will cause it to develop resistance that kind of breakage. Of course, the code doesn't get stronger by itself; it requires more developer effort for this to happen. And people will quite reasonably complain about having to do this additional work.

But the "toughening" of application code is in some sense secondary to the other goal of preserving the freedom to change the implementation. Preserving iteration order of `HashMap` has made it more difficult to maintain. Randomized iteration order in the new collections means that we needn't worry about preserving iteration order when modifying them, so they're easier to maintain and enhance.

For example, the current implementation (Java 9, pre-GA, July 2017) has three field-based implementations of Set (`Set0`, `Set1`, and `Set2`) and an array-based implementation (`SetN`) that uses a simple closed hashing with linear probing scheme. In the future, we might want to add a `Set3` implementation that holds three elements in three fields. Or, we might want to change the collision resolution policy of `SetN` from linear probing to something more sophisticated. We can completely restructure the implementation, even in minor releases, if we don't have to deal with preserving iteration order.

In summary, the tradeoff is that application developers have to do more work to make sure their code resists breakage from iteration order change. This is likely work they'd have to do at some point anyway with `HashMap`. What's gained by this is more opportunities for the JDK to deliver improved performance and space efficiency, from which everybody can benefit.

Comment: Hi Stuart, thank you very much for this. I think you mentioned this in that talk, especially the part about how difficult it is to maintain `HashMap` if you need to keep iteration order stable. However, don't know why, I kept what I quoted and kind of dismissed this other reason you are stating here. I know there are no secrets here :) I just wanted to further know about the motivations and the problems you were trying to tackle.

Comment: I could imagine a “`Set` deduplication”, similar to the `String` deduplication feature. For a `Set` that survived long enough to get this treatment, more time for finding a better table size/collision resolution parameters could be spent. Then, the iteration order would not change in every iteration, but may change in a `Set`’s lifetime. Of course, that applies only to the immutable sets.

Comment: @Holger that is absolutely an interesting idea!

Comment: @Holger Yes, interesting idea. I think it's analogous to how `HashMap` can dynamically change its internal representation from a linked list to a tree as circumstances warrant. The specification for immutable sets and maps is silent on how often iteration order can change, but I hope the current randomization scheme (once per JVM instance) is frequent enough that making iteration order changes somewhat more frequently shouldn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 6):

That quote and your thoughts around already make a strong argument in favor of doing this. So what else do you need?

In other words: one of the "fathers" of Java declares that *their* motivation for "random map/set order" is to "educate" Java programmers to not expect or even rely on any special order. Therefore the answer (probably opinionated is) - question your expectation.

The people in charge told you about their thoughts to do this. There is no reason to assume that they are "hiding" other motivation for this design decision.

To the contrary: one could probably find arguments *against* spending **extra** effort to achieve this amount of randomness - the JVM is probably spending quite some extra CPU cycles - just to *achieve* indeterministic behavior (something that we normally try to avoid at all cost).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Yes, I agree with you in that educating programmers is enough motivation. I didn't mean there was another, secret motivation, I just want to know if there are other motivations, i.e. help protect applications of some specific attack based on hash codes, etc. And what can you tell about the advantages?

Comment: @GhostCat: Just a note on the extra effort. There is some or course, but when you look at the implementation you'll find that it is really nifty and adds next to zero overhead and only during creation.